# Rename and Move S3 files based on their folders name in pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am wringing some dataframes using partitionBy to S3. The folder structure that gets created is as below.

```
root/
    date=2018-01-01/
    date=2018-01-02/
```

I want to move these files to another directory in s3 and rename the folders as

```
root1/
       20180101/
       20180102/
```

Is there a way that I can achieve this from pyspark?

Also i need the files to be renamed in a sequential way inside the directories,e.g :

```
root1/
     20180101/FILE_1.csv
     20180101/FILE_2.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly rename S3 objects.

So one way to achieve this is to copy the objects to have desirable name and then delete the original objects.

Also, S3 buckets do not have a directory structure, "directory structure" is just prefixes in the objects' keys.

You have two options, either call aws cli from python using subprocees or use boto3 library to copy all the files from one "directory" to another.

Solution using subprocess:

```
  import subprocess
  subprocess.check_call("aws s3 sync s3://bucket/root/date=2018-01-01/ s3://bucket/root1/20180101/".split())
```

sync command will copy recursively. Then you can use  `aws s3 rm --recursive "somepath"` . Call it using subprocess again.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question, also i am looking for renaming the files in a sequential manner. any idea, how can i achieve this?

Comment: I do not understand. Could you provide output of my method versus desired output? By sequential you mean recursive?

Comment: You can ignore my comment about the sequential part.